# Determining Website Crash Time on Linux Server

Tags: linux, logging, server

2.5 months ago, I was running a website on a Linux server to do a user study on 3 variations of a tool. All 3 variations ran on the same website. While I was conducting my user study, the website (i.e., process hosting the website) crashed. In my sleep-deprived state, I unfortunately did not record when the crash happened. However, **I now need to know a) when the crash happened, and b) for how long the website was down until I brought it back up**. I only have a rough timeframe for when the crash happened and for long it was down, but I need to pinpoint this information as precisely as possible to do some time-on-task analyses with my user study data.

The server runs **Linux 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-165-generic x86_64) and has been minimally set up to run our website**. As such, it is unlikely that any utilities aside from those that came with the OS have been installed. Similarly, no additional setup has likely been done. For example, I tried looking at a history of commands used in hopes that HISTTIMEFORMAT was previously set so that I could see timestamps. This ended up not being the case; while I can now see timestamps for commands, setting HISTTIMEFORMAT is not retroactive, meaning I can't get accurate timestamps for the commands I ran 2.5 months ago. That all being said, if you have an idea that you think might work, I'm willing to try (as long as it doesn't break our server)!

It is also worth mentioning that **I currently do not know if it's possible to see a remote desktop or something of the like**; I've been just ssh'ing in and use the terminal to interact with the server.

I've been bouncing ideas off with friends and colleagues, and we all feel that there must be SOMETHING we could use to pinpoint when the server went down (e.g., network activity logs showing spikes around the time that the user study began as well as when the website was revived, a log of previous/no longer running processes, etc.). Unfortunately, none of us know about Linux logs or commands to really dig deep into this very specific issue.

**In summary:**

- I need a timestamp for either when the website crashed or when it was revived. It would be nice to have both (or otherwise determine for how long the website was down for), but this is not completely necessary
- I'm guessing only a "native" Linux command will be useful since nothing new/special has been installed on our server. Otherwise, any additional command/tool/utility will have to be retroactive.
- It may or may not be possible to get a remote desktop working with the server (e.g., to use some tool that has a GUI you interact with to help get some information)
- Myself and my colleagues have that sense of "there must be SOMETHING we could use" between various logs or system information, such at network activity, process start times, etc., but none of us know enough about Linux to do deep digging without some help

**Any ideas for what I can try to help figure out at least when the website crashed (if not also for how long it was down)?**

Comment: What webserver or process was running your website? Many such programs will by default write to a log file, which is generally timestamped and would potentially contain the exit reason and boot-up time.

Comment: More generally, you may be able to use the `last` command from the terminal to view when you logged into the system back when the server crashed: https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/difference-between-utmp-wtmp-files-in-linux/

Comment: I was using a Node.js server, which I didn't think did any auto-logging like that. If it does, do you know where I should look for the log files?

While I could look at the timestamp for when I logged into the server that day, I purposefully remained logged in for the entire duration of the user study. Therefore, the crash happened much later after I logged in. I need something more accurate than that

Comment: Node by default wouldn't log anything, so it depends more specifically on your application. If the application just logged to standard output, which is possible, then any output from back then is lost to the ether. It would be worth checking the directory from which you ran the program to see if any `*.log` files exist.

Comment: Also, were you running Node directly exposed over port 80, or were you using a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx)? You could check to see if `/var/log/nginx/access.log` exists, as if so it would have logged the users' requests.

Comment: It does look like we have some basic logging and debugging functionality set up, but it prints to STDOUT: `var express = require('express'); var app = express(); var http = require('http').Server(app); var debug = require('debug')('Nebula:server'); var logger = require('morgan'); app.use(logger('dev')); function onListening() {
  var addr = http.address();
  var bind = (typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port);
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}`  Given that it all prints without timestamps too (I'm 90% certain), I don't think this will have the info I'm looking for

Comment: As for the port, we are using port 80

Comment: Yeah, both Morgan and debug will log only to stdout/stderr by default, so unless you were redirecting those to a file when you ran the command, those outputs are lost. Since the app logs are out, the next layer up is the Linux server logs, but network traffic and port bindings etc are not logged by default, so I’m not hopeful. My next vector to look at would be any side effects that your tool might have — does it write to a database? Connect to Redis? Make external web calls? These things might generate logs you could analyze.

Comment: No, it unfortunately does not do any of those things. It's pretty much a self-contained system. It does read local data (in flat files) to use in the app as people connect to it, so I did just check when these files were last opened/read. Sadly, they have been read since the user study

Comment: Was there anything else in-between the users and this server that might have logged the interactions? A load balancer, for example? Or were users just connecting to a direct IP address to use this tool? Also, did you have Google Analytics or any other client-side tracking turned on within the app’s frontend? These are outside of the scope of your question but are all I’ve got left to suggest.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think we have anything like that... The website was accessed using an actual domain name (as opposed to an IP address), but as far as I know, there was no logging on the domain's end. (I'm not even sure how to check... If you know how, I can give it a try.) We weren't using Google Analytics or any other monitoring or tracking tools

Comment: I'm sad that it appears Linux doesn't keep any timestamped logs of any sort (network traffic, terminal commands, processes, etc.) that we could use to better determine when the website crashed.... Definitely let me know if you think of something else I could try though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine pointed me to the `journalctl` command, which apparently maintains timestamps of past commands separately from HISTTIMEFORMAT and keeps logs that for me went as far back as October 7. It contained enough information for me to determine both when I revived my Node js server as well as when my Node js server initially went down